# get margin-left using jquery not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

The below code is working fine in chrome but not in firefox.  the alert shows proper margin in chrome while in firefox it always shows `0px`.

HTML:

```
<div class="center">14</div>
```

CSS:

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

JQuery:
 I am using latest jQuery Library

```
$(function(){
    var center = $('.center').css('margin-left');
    alert(center);
});
```

Please see the jsfiddle in both firefox and chrome:
http://jsfiddle.net/vtbuz/2/

Comment: What does is show in Chrome?

Comment: It is showing the margin-left value in px but in firefox it's always 0px http://jsfiddle.net/vtbuz/2/ see this fiddle in both chrome and firefox

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your own question and then accept it. This helps other readers and keeps the site a valuable resource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a solution:

```
var center = $('.center').offset().left;
```

by using this we can get the proper left position relative to document.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in Firefox, so unfortunately you can't fix it at the moment.
Firefox returns `0px` instead of the desired output.

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11110
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=381328

Comment: Thanks for updating me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Change `margin-left` to `marginLeft`

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rWbFw/173/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this for defining margin in FF: @-moz-document url-prefix() { (css rules) }

Answer (score 0):

> Retrieval of shorthand CSS properties (e.g., margin, background,
>   border), although functional with some browsers, is not guaranteed.
>   For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered border-width, use:
>   $( elem ).css( "borderTopWidth" ), $( elem ).css( "borderBottomWidth"
>   ), and so on

http://api.jquery.com/css/

You can try

```
$('.center').css('marginLeft');
```

Comment: @KrishnaPalSingh Looks like it work's on firefox if you set that property in css .. see demo --> http://jsfiddle.net/vtbuz/7/

Comment: but I want calculate the center div margin-left property.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
var center = $('.center').css("margin-left" : "200px");
```

If you want to retrive value of css; use parseInt() around the result to turn it in to the number value.

```
var center = parseInt($('.center').css("margin-left"));
```

**Final Solution**

Working Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/tsspinal/zVr6W/1/

```
$(function(){
    var center = $('.center').css('marginLeft');
    alert(center);
    var left = ((parseInt($(window).width() - $('.center').width()) / 2)-8 + "px");
    alert(left);
});
```

Comment: I am trying to get the margin-left property using jquery not want to set it.

Comment: Edited my answer. I hope that will help

Comment: dude, see my code parseInt only give 0 instead off 0px. see the fiddle

Comment: Got it fixed. Please check demo code on jsfiddle. if you'll notice i have added static number **8** in calculation for **var left**. I don't know but if you'll remove it it always gives to results with difference of 8. So I just abstracted it.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it looks bizarre for me as we can use the offset().left property to get the same thing. Anyway thanks for your help...